# When using a chevron should I use one or two?

Tags: toggle, collapsing

I am using a chevron for hiding and collapsing an area on my interface. I have found versions of chevrons out there that use 2, and others that use a single:

[image]

**Is there any standard or reason to favor one over the other?**

Comment: My only comment would be for the Web when using horizontal chevrons like this: « Left and Right » to use the double (if done using text).  The reason is that often a single less-than or greater-than character can be mistaken as an HTML parsing glitch and thus looks odd >

Comment: @scunfliffe +1 agreed, the double chevron &#187; simply looks better than the &gt; many website have used the double chevron in their text links/buttons for this reason

Comment: I was about to answer...then I lost interest.  Let the graphic designer choose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I highly recommend doing some [A/B testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A/B_testing) on simple things like these. That being said, they wont make a *significant* difference between users unless there is some ambiguity in the interface.

Typically I'd use the double-chevron when the distance of collapse is larger (`>50%` of interface size), and the single when the distance is smaller (`<25%`).

You might have noticed that there's a gap from 25–50%, where I use my gut instinct.

Comment: +1 Awesome thanks! I was leaning toward double, and yes it is collapsing about 1/3, so win/win there.

Comment: I don't see how A/B testing is going to provide any useful results whatsoever if that's the only change being tested.

Comment: @Charles Boyung, A/B testing is just testing usage between two options. It doesn't have to be A/B/N testing for this case. All I was saying was to try it both ways and see which one works better.

Comment: @zzzzBov - I know what A/B testing is. I'm saying that with something so trivial as this, you won't get any significant data to prove one is more usable than the other.

Comment: @Charles Boyung, Rather than *assume* that you wont get any significant data, [run a test](https://www.google.com/analytics/siteopt/splash?hl=en) and see whether the **results** indicate that there isn't a significant difference.